# Compilation tag throwing error in web.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, web-config

I have the following error in VS2010

> Sections must only appear once per config file.  See the help topic 
>    for exceptions.

It's pointing at the compilation tag, nested within the  tag.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation>
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..."/>
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
</system.web>
```

There are no other  tags within the web.config.

Comment: is there another Compilation section somewhere in your web.config?

Comment: What else is in your web.config

Comment: @n8wrl, sorry I forgot to mention there's no other compilation tags.

Comment: @BugFinder, there's a lot in the web.config file...  679 lines of comments and code.  Should I look for something specific?

Comment: Can you post the entire file? There is another compilation tag in there somewhere. Maybe buried in comments but not really a comment?

Comment: You need to look at the `web.config` files in each of the folders leading to the root directory - it could be that a `web.config` in one of those already adds this library, or that it is added in the machine wide `web.config` that is in the framework directory.

Comment: @n8wrl, I'm not that comfortable pasting everything...  I'm sure there's no other compilation tags, but I did find the same reference tag.  Issue is, when I remove it, it breaks the cs files that used it...

Comment: @Oded, from what I see, there are no other web.config files

Comment: Try this - delete everything EXCEPT the compilation tag you showed us. Hit the site, which will probably fail, but not the same way. Add stuff back a little at a time until you get the dup-section error again.

Comment: In visual studio there is often Web.config and underneath a debug and release, where it will add sections. If you cant post the whole thing, then you really need to go through it, either you have some other partial tag, or, you have a dup its just lying about where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My money is on a mal-formed comment or something - there has to be another compilation tag in there somewhere.

EDIT:

Try this - delete everything EXCEPT the compilation tag you showed us. Hit the site, which will probably fail, but not the same way. Add stuff back a little at a time until you get the dup-section error again